# Prove that if $(ab)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}$ then $(ab)^2 = a^2b^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a group with $a,b \in G$. I'm currently trying to prove a TFAE statement and I've shown the two other implications ($G$ abelian $\implies (ab)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}$ and $(ab)^2 = a^2b^2 \implies$ $G$ abelian), but I'm struggling in showing that $(ab)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1} \implies (ab)^2 = a^2b^2$. All I have so far is that $(ab)^2 = abab$. I'm not really sure what I'm doing, so I started taking left and right inverses of both sides until I got $a^{-1}(ab)^2b^{-1} = ba$, but I soon realized my efforts were achieving no progress. I can't think of a way to actually use the assumption.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ implies $(ab)a^{-1}b^{-1}=1$,thus $ab=ba$ and $(ab)^2=abab=bbaa$.